# javascript, oop - change variable from inside a class

Tags: javascript, oop, class

Good day to all.

I hava a js class that contains more functions that do... something. Mainly they set variables.

My problem is that I need to set a variable in the "mother" script that uses the class, from inside a class method, without expressly requesting this from the script.

Ex. Let's say I need to set flag to 1.

```
 var flag = 0;

 someName.something = new Class({

 ..........
 testSomething:function(id){
     //lots and lots of functions that EVENTUALY gets to this:
     if(id)
     {
        this.setFlag();
     }
 }

 setFlag:function(){
     flag = 1;
     return flag;
 }
 ..........

 });
```

To set the flag I can use something like

```
 flag = something.setFlag();
```

The problem is that I can't use that method directly, I have to run testSomething() first, and that function might run for hours after I need to set the flag, so I need to set it from inside the class with something like

```
 parentScript.flag = 1; (and this sets the flag)
```

Hope I was clear in what I need :)... if any1 can help me... ty.

Comment: You weren't exactly clear.. the example you provided works fine - you can set the global variable `flag` to anything from within any method in your `something` instance of `Class`. So where's the problem? It all works.

Comment: I know it works perfectly. But I don't need to CALL the method. I need to call a method that runs for hours. Somewhere inside that method I need to set a flag in the parent script. A flag that is used by another method, of another class (but that's not the problem) that runs in the same time as the method that IS POSSIBLE to set the flag. Something like a method is doing something and another is testing where it got with the progress.

Comment: Yes, the flag is global.

Comment: If it's a global variable, just set it from whever you like! Or do you want a flag per instance of the class?

Comment: Also, if you want to test progress, why not use console.log() or something similar to that?

Comment: I tried to set it. It doesn't get the value. And... I also need one per instance :).

Comment: I don't want to test the progress... I said is similar.

Comment: If you need one per instance, don't use a global variable.

Comment: I try to use a global vector actually. I simplified the question as much as I could. I do this: somewhere in motherscript: var flag = 0;. Somewhere inside the method flag = 1 (also tried window.flag = 1). Then inside the method that runs in the same time (is calling itself until flag is 1 so timing is not a problem) I used: alert(flag);. Is always 0 (and i'm sure is set, i replaced the initial conditions with 1==1 to be sure it gets there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I used:

motherscript:
  var flag = 0;

class method:

window.flag = 1;

I tried this earlier but it didn't work the first time... probably I did something wrong and didn't notice it,